# Is there an analogy to twin primes in the rational integers among the Gaussian and Eisenstein integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, euclidean-domain

Twin primes, like (29, 31) and (137, 139) are interesting to study. I have been exploring the parallels of the Gaussian and Eisenstein integers with the rational integers. For instance, they have primes and composites in common. But are there "twin primes"? There may not be a direct analogy, since the relationships > and < are ambiguous in the Gaussian and Eisenstein integers - unless you are talking about the norm.

Comment: You don't need $>$ and $<$ to talk about twin primes in the integers, all you need is $|p-q|=2$.

Comment: Daniel Shanks, A note on Gaussian twin primes, https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1960-14-070/S0025-5718-1960-0111724-0/S0025-5718-1960-0111724-0.pdf

Comment: Derong Qiu and Xianke Zhang, Elliptic curves of twin primes over Gauss field and Diophantine equations, Adv. Math. (China) 29 (2000), no. 3, 279-281. Mathematical Review 1 789 429 may be relevant. Also, C. A. Holben and J. H. Jordan, J. H., The twin prime problem and Goldbach's conjecture in the Gaussian integers, Fibonacci Quart. 6 1968 no. 5, 81-85, 92

Comment: Discussion on math.stackexchange, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884143/about-the-distribution-of-gaussian-prime-pairs, also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373438/gaps-between-gaussian-primes